# Stop the form of beign submitted on "Save changes" custom option page

Tags: plugins, settings-api, validation

Using the Settings API of Wordpress i want to try cancel the submission of the options when the validation/sanitization fails.

Registering the settings:

```
register_setting( 'mysettingspage', 'custom_options', 'input_validation' );
```

My validation function:

```
function input_validation( $input ){

settings_errors('custom_options');

$options = get_option( 'custom_options' );

// Create our array for storing the validated options
$output = array();

// Loop through each of the incoming options
foreach( $input as $key => $value ) {

        // Check to see if the current option has a value. If so, process it.
        if( isset( $input[$key] ) ) {

            // Strip all HTML and PHP tags and properly handle quoted strings
            $output[$key] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $input[ $key ] ) );

        } // end if

        //check if its not empty
            if(empty($value)){

                add_settings_error(
                    'custom_options',
                    'Missing value error',
                    __('On or more fields can\'t be empty.', 'custom'),
                    'error'
                );

                return array();
            } 

        } // end if


    } // end foreach

    // Return the array processing any additional functions filtered by this action
    return $output;
}
```

The problem is, even if no options are saved, wordpress still gonna display a message "Settings Saved" and save the empty array of option in the database.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Try remove the `settings_errors('custom_options');` or comment it out `//settings_errors('custom_options');`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that removes the errors and not the "Settings Saved".

Comment: How did you call the `input_validation()` function? You should probably better add the code to your question.

Comment: I edited my question to include the way the function is called.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So I'm guessing that you're creating a test settings page? If so, can I see the whole code? Because I tested your `input_validation()` code and it actually worked. However, not sure if you intended it, but I think the `return array();` should be `return $options;` to return the old value.

Comment: Hi thanks for checking, yes indeed my code does work, even gives errors, my problem is that i want it to not save (or better not show the "Settings Saved" message) when the validation fails (when returning array()).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've posted an answer, and although it may not exactly answer the question, I hope that it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to stop the *form data* from being *saved* on error

Actually, the "Settings saved." message does *not* necessarily mean that the options/value *in the database* was actually updated — because if the old and new values were the same, means there were no changes, then the old value will *not* be re-saved or overwritten in the database. However, you'd still see the "Settings saved." message which indicates that the form (data) was successfully submitted and processed without errors.

Hence, when the form data contains empty or invalid values, you should *return the old options and not an empty `array`*. Please see below, which is *your* code, but it's slightly modified so that you could hopefully understand what I mean:

```
function input_validation( $input ){

//settings_errors('custom_options'); // <- this should NOT be here..

$options = get_option( 'custom_options' ); // <- here's the OLD VALUE

// Create our array for storing the validated options
$output = array();

// Loop through each of the incoming options
foreach( $input as $key => $value ) {

        ... your code here ...

        //check if its not empty
            if(empty($value)){

                add_settings_error(
                    'custom_options',
                    'Missing value error',
                    __('On or more fields can\'t be empty.', 'custom'),
                    'error'
                );

                //return array(); // <- here don't return empty array
                return $options; // <- instead, return the old value
            } // end if


    } // end foreach

    // Return the array processing any additional functions filtered by this action
    return $output; // <- even if all form data are VALID, this/$output
                    // could still be the same as $options (i.e. there
                    // were no changes made)
}
```

`//settings_errors('custom_options'); // <- this should NOT be here..` — Why not?

That's because the `settings_errors()` function is *automatically* called on your custom options page (provided it was created using the WordPress [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/)), therefore there's no need to manually call the function — just add settings errors and they'll be displayed automatically.

> This is called *automatically* after a **settings page** *based on the
>   Settings API is **submitted***. Errors should be added during the
>   validation callback function for a setting defined in
>   `register_setting()`.

— See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/settings_errors/

### How to stop the *form* from being *submitted* on error

1. If you just want to make sure the form fields are all filled in, add
   (the HTML5 attribute of) `required` to the field's HTML. For examples:

   ```
   <input name="custom_options[option_1]" type="text" required>
   <select name="custom_options[option_2]" required></select>
   <textarea name="custom_options[option_3]" required></textarea>
   ```
2. Use JavaScript validation. Here's a very simple example:
   (using jQuery)

   ```
   <form method="post" action="options.php" id="my-form">
     <input name="custom_options[option_1]" type="text" id="option-1">
     <select name="custom_options[option_2]" id="option-2">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       <option value="1">One</option>
     </select>
     <textarea name="custom_options[option_3]" id="option-3"></textarea>
     <input type="submit">
   </form>

   <script>
   $('#my-form').on('submit', function(){
     if ( // check if all fields are filled
       $('#option-1', this).val().length < 1 ||
       $('#option-2', this).val().length < 1 ||
       $('#option-3', this).val().length < 1
     ) {
       alert('Please fill in all fields.');
       return false; // cancels the submit
     }
   });
   </script>
   ```

Try a demo [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjvbqy?editors=1010).

---

So basically, in the `input_validation()` function, the *form* has already been submitted. To prevent that, you can use client-side validation like I mentioned above — the HTML5 and jQuery validation.

Comment: Thank you for the help! That was the answer that i was looking for!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. =)